# Using a file to store a calendar

Tags: c, file, calendar

I am somewhat new to C. I'm making a calendar for a full year and storing it  into a file. My main problem is that whenever I try and make a file it comes out blank. I've been trying to figure this out for a while and decided to finally ask. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MIN_YEAR  2000
#define MAX_YEAR  3000
#define JANUARY   1
#define FEBRUARY  2
#define MARCH     3
#define APRIL     4
#define MAY       5
#define JUNE      6
#define JULY      7
#define AUGUST    8
#define SEPTEMBER 9
#define OCTOBER   10
#define NOVEMBER  11
#define DECEMBER  12

bool getContinueChoice();
int  getYear          ();
int  getStartingDay   (int year);
bool isLeapYear       (int year);
void makeFile         (int year, int startingDay);
void makeMonthHeading (int month, int year, FILE *file);
int  getNumberOfDays  (int month, int year);

int main()
{
   int startingDay,
       year;

   printInstructions();

   while(getContinueChoice() == true)
   {
      year        = getYear(); 
      startingDay = getStartingDay(year);
      makeFile(year, startingDay);
      printf("\nCalendar made for the year %d.\n", year);
      printf("Look for the file called file.txt to see it.\n");
   }

   printGoodbye();

   return 0;
}

bool getContinueChoice()
{
   char getChoice;
   bool choice;

   scanf(" %c", &getChoice);

   while(getChoice != 'y' || 'n')
   {
      printf("\n***************************************\n");
      printf("* Error: That was not a (y/n) answer. *\n");
      printf("***************************************\n\n");
      printf("Would you like to print a calendar? (y/n): ");
      scanf(" %c", &getChoice);
   }

   if(getChoice == 'y')
   {
      choice = true;
   }
   else
   {
      choice = false;
   }

   return choice;
}

int getYear()
{
   int userYear;

   printf("\nPlease enter a year.\n");
   scanf("%d", &userYear);

   return userYear;
}

int getStartingDay(int year)
{
   int firstDay;   

   firstDay = (((year - 1) * 365) + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + 
               ((year - 1) / 400) + 1) % 7;

return firstDay;
}

bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
   bool leapYear;

   if((!(year % 4) && (year % 100)) || !(year % 400))
   {
      leapYear = true;
   }

   return leapYear;
}

void makeFile(int year, int startingDay)
{
   int   daysInMonth;  
   FILE *file;

   file = fopen("file.txt","w");

   for(int month = JANUARY; month <= DECEMBER; month++)
   {         
      makeMonthHeading(month, year, file);

      fprintf(file, "SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT\n");

      for(int day = 1; day <= 1 + startingDay * 5; day++)
      {
         printf(" ");

         daysInMonth = getNumberOfDays(month, year);      

         for(int days = 1; days <= daysInMonth; days++)
         {
            fprintf(file, "%2d", days);

            if((days + startingDay) % 7 > 0)
            {
               printf(" ");
            }
            else
            {
               printf("\n");
            }
         }
      }  
   }

   printf("Calendar made for the year %d", year);
   printf("\nLook for the file called file.txt to see it.\n\n");

   getContinueChoice();

   return;

}

void makeMonthHeading(int month, int year, FILE *file)
{
   if(month == JANUARY)
   {
      fprintf(file, "JANUARY           %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == FEBRUARY)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nFEBRUARY           %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == MARCH)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nMARCH             %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == APRIL)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nAPRIL             %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == MAY)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nMAY               %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == JUNE)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nJUNE              %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == JULY)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nJULY              %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == AUGUST)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nAUGUST            %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == SEPTEMBER)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nSEPTEMBER         %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == OCTOBER)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nOCTOBER           %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == NOVEMBER)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nNOVEMBER          %d\n", year);
   }
   else if(month == DECEMBER)
   {
      fprintf(file, "\nDECEMBER          %d\n", year);
   }

   return;
}

int getNumberOfDays(int month, int year)
{
   int  monthDays;

   if(month == JANUARY)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == FEBRUARY)
   { 
      if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
      {
         monthDays = 29;
      }
      else
      {
         monthDays = 28;
      }
   }
   else if(month == MARCH)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == APRIL)
   {
      monthDays = 30;
   }
   else if(month == MAY)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == JUNE)
   {
      monthDays = 30;
   }
   else if(month == JULY)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == AUGUST)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == SEPTEMBER)
   {
      monthDays = 30;
   }
   else if(month == OCTOBER)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }
   else if(month == NOVEMBER)
   {
      monthDays = 30;
   }
   else if(month == DECEMBER)
   {
      monthDays = 31;
   }

   return monthDays;
}
```

Comment: This long scroll of `if`s can be done with one simple array.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] using the hints given here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: You do not close the file, but the variable falls out of scope.

Comment: fclose() after you're done with writing data to file

Comment: I used fclose(), but now im having an issue with the yes and no while loop. It won't stop looping regardless of input.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues on the same line:

```
while(getChoice != 'y' || 'n')
```

- This does not do what you think it does. Let's work on an example, where `getChoice = 'a'`

  First operation `getChoice != 'y'` will evaluate to `TRUE` because `'a' != 'y'`. Remember you are getting `TRUE` out of this operation.

  Now, you are left with `TRUE || 'n'` which always be `TRUE`

  So, your while condition will always be `TRUE` and this is why you are stuck in that loop.

If you fix that with

```
while((getChoice != 'y') || (getChoice != 'n'))
```

You will realize your second problem with that line, which is your logic.

- Imagine if the user enters `'y'`. Then what happens?

  `(getChoice != 'y')` will be `FALSE`, but `(getChoice != 'n')` will be `TRUE`, so your while condition will be `TRUE` and you will be stuck in that loop again.

  Think about other scenarios and then you will come to a conclusion that you need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

So, change that line to:

```
while((getChoice != 'y') && (getChoice != 'n'))
```

Also, as @purec said, you need to `fclose()` the file once you are done with it.